# Comprobar si una cadena es una fecha

Tags: java

Estoy comprobando la entrada de datos de un servicio en Java, concretamente las fechas.

Al recibir los datos por JSON, las supuestas fechas vienen en formato String y necesito comprobar si la String es una fecha válida.
El problema es que el formato de la fecha puede ser:

```
 "dropDate": "2021-06-22T12:18:13.406+02:00", -- Tiene T y .
 "dropDate": "2021-06-22 12:18:13", -- yyyy- Sin T y sin .
 "dropDate": "22-06-2021 12:18:13", -- dd con guión
 "dropDate": "2021/06/2022 12:18:13",--  yyyy con /
 "dropDate": "22/06/2021 12:18:13", -- dd/ ---> esta es la que quiero (las otras fechas son válidas, pero se tienen que convertir a este formato).
ETC
```

Yo estaba usando el:

```
SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
fecha = formato.parse(member.getDropDate());
```

Como se puede ver, hay muchas fechas diferentes,pero yo necesito que cualquier entrada, se convierta en una `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

Pero la aplicación está fallando porque el formato de fechas que se está recibiendo no es el `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`, desde mi punto de vista esto lo tendría que hacer automáticamente el SimpleDateFormat (detectar cual es el formato y pasarlo al que le he dicho).

Al final intentando `Date date = new Date(member.getDropDate())` -> También da error que no se puede parsear.

Gracias.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226910/how-to-sanity-check-a-date-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Como ya se ha mencionado antes, debido a la multiplicidad de formatos de fecha-hora, la única manera es probar para encontrar la conversión correcta. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Fechas {
    
    public static LocalDateTime convertirFecha(String cadenaFechaOrigen, DateTimeFormatter formato)
    {        
        LocalDateTime fechaHora=LocalDateTime.now();       
        
        try{
            
            fechaHora = LocalDateTime.parse(cadenaFechaOrigen, formato);               
            System.out.println("Aviso: Se aplicó el formato: "+formato.toString());            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {            
            System.out.println("Error: Falló al aplicar el formato: "+formato.toString());            
        }   
        return fechaHora;     
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
               
        String cadenaFechaOrigen = "2021-06-22T12:18:13.406+02:00";
        String cadenaFormato;
        LocalDateTime fechaHoraDevuelta=LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formato;
        
        //Probar la conversión con los diferentes formatos
        cadenaFormato="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        formato = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(cadenaFormato);
        fechaHoraDevuelta=convertirFecha(cadenaFechaOrigen,formato);       
        
        cadenaFormato="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
        formato = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(cadenaFormato);
        fechaHoraDevuelta=convertirFecha(cadenaFechaOrigen,formato);      
        
        cadenaFormato="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
        formato = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(cadenaFormato);
        fechaHoraDevuelta=convertirFecha(cadenaFechaOrigen,formato);               
        
        formato= DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME; 
        fechaHoraDevuelta=convertirFecha(cadenaFechaOrigen,formato);

        String fechaHoraFormateada = fechaHoraDevuelta.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        System.out.println("Fecha: "+fechaHoraFormateada);
        
    }
}
```

Para mayor referencia https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html